# How to remove a specific string from file name

Tags: files, rename

I have a report running in UNIX and creating a file named `xxxx_ddmmyy_hhmm_zzzzzz.txt`. I need to remove the `zzzzzz` from the file name.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

use `mv` comand like this :

```
mv old-file-name  new-file-name
```

in this case :

```
mv xxxx_ddmmyy_hhmm_zzzzzz.txt xxxx_ddmmyy_hhmm.txt.
```

To make mv interactive pass the -i option. This option will prompt before overwriting file:

`mv -i file1 file2`

Sample outputs: `mv: overwrite 'file2'? y`

Comment: Thank you. But ddmmyy and hhmm are parameters of date and time and i do not know them. The only thing i know for sure is the zzzzzz which i need to remove.

Comment: so you must use a shell command !